# Auto Refresh Grid in EXTJS after a record is Inserted on server

Tags: javascript, ajax, extjs

I am using EXTJs4 and I want to reload the Grid only after a record is Inserted in the Data Base. Currently I am using Task runner to reload the store every 1 minute. 
Here is the sample :

```
var store = grid.getStore();    
var refreshTask = {             
    run: function() {
        store.reload();
    },
    interval: 60 * 1000 
};
```

Ext.util.TaskRunner.start(refreshTask);

I'm not sure how I can write a function only to reload when a data is Inserted in the data base ?

Comment: You can use async/await for achieving your goal

Comment: How are the rows inserted? By your app or by other users using other means?

Comment: @LorenzMeyer , other users are inserting records. After they have uploaded the record ,values are inserted in the table and only after the insertion My page should get Auto Refreshed with the new record.

Answer (score 0):

There are various ways to get an instant response from the server once something changes, the most compatible are so-called "Hanging Request".

What you do is you send a request to the server, and the server does not answer instantly. The server instead waits until changes are there (it lets the request "hang", hence the name), and only sends a reply after that, or after a predefined timeout. (This behaviour has to be supported by your server-side code, obviously).

This cannot be implemented with `store.load` or other store functions on the client side; you will have to use `Ext.Ajax.request` and evaluate the response manually, e.g. call `store.loadRawData` from the request callback to load the changed records into the store.